# Architecture/tools/technologies for high performance image streaming application - Java

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

Currently, we have Java webservices in both REST and SOAP that streams images to the Swing client. The Swing client is like a Video player with controls Play, Move forward, etc. It calls the Webservice and displays images. When you play, it has to get images (jpeg) continuously and display them so simulate a video. There are other custom controls as well, like move forward, which pulls an image at some given point.

Tomcat Server
Spring MVC REST
Swing (Client)
Java 1.7
2 servers on AWS

On the server, the webservice calls AWS API to pull the images. The images are sent as a raw bytes.

Currently, the performance is a problem. When the Swing viewer loads, we pull x number of images and start playing, while its playing, we pull same x number of images and cache them locally.

I don't think more servers would solve the problem here. We need to figure out a good architecture to boost the performance. What could be done?

Any idea?

Comment: A bit of a tangential question, but is the Swing client meant to really simulate a video player? It almost sounds like you have reinvented a streaming video protocol by loading jpegs one at a time to simulate movie frames.

Comment: Right. But we have a lot of other custom controls to be done on images/playing. not just a simple image viewing stuff.

Comment: Can you have the client request the images directly from AWS instead of proxying them through your own servers?

Comment: I don't want to. Because there are other stuff that are done in the server side and this service not just for the image serving, it does other things as well. And I guess, its a bad idea too, to push this task to clients.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "performance is a problem"? Did you analyze the performance and break it down between the components of your application, e.g. network overhead between AWS and Tomcat/between Tomcat and the Swing client/Tomcat processing time/ client processing time? Which part(s) is a bottleneck? How do you "pull the images" from AWS? One at a time? Can you provide more details on how you use AWS to store and retrieve the images? Are you using an S3 bucket, or maybe some database service?